# how to remove quotation marks string before and after a string in R

Tags: r

I've tried several ways i found here but i haven't gotten the result i need, I need to be able to remove the " "" that appears on the first column and on the last column remove the " that appears at the end because the data base runs for several thousand the number of digits increases.

what is constant is the " "" on the first column and the " on the last column

```
db <- structure(list(`"1""Name` = c("\"2\"\"AAFC", "\"3\"\"Adfd",
"\"4\"\"Abbb"), `References"` = c("3\"", "4\"", "4\"")), row.names = c(NA,
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all the occurrence of `'"'` from all the columns you can use `lapply` with `gsub` :

```
db[] <- lapply(db, function(x) gsub('"', '', x))
db

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  `"1""Name` `References"`
#  <chr>      <chr>        
#1 2AAFC      3            
#2 3Adfd      4            
#3 4Abbb      4
```

If there are lot of columns and you want to do this only for selected columns we can subset those columns and pass to `lapply`. For example, for first and last column we can do :

```
cols <- c(1, ncol(db))
db[cols] <- lapply(db[cols], function(x) gsub('"', '', x))
```

Answer (score 3):

If we need to remove the leading/lagging `"`, use `trimws` with `whitespace` specifying the regex pattern

```
library(dplyr)
db1 <- db %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ trimws(., whitespace = '"')))
```

Or use `str_remove_all` to remove all the double quotes

```
library(stringr)
db1  <- db %>%
         mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_remove_all(., '"')))
```

Comment: yes, it removes the first and last quotation mark  but that leaves still 2""AAFC in the first column

Comment: @MannyMa i thoughht you want to remove the leading and lagging '"'

Comment: yes and also the quotation marks in the middle, my mistake on not being precise enough in my question,

Comment: sometimes with 'separate' leaving a whitespace provokes a quotation mark at least in the screen I avoided them just removing the whitespace `db %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_remove_all(., ' ')))` instead of removing the "